# WebView - Hiding a div with getElementById doesn't work instantly

Tags: javascript, android

I have a `Fragment` with a `WebView` and I want to hide certain divs. It works, but these divs do not hide instantly and can be seen - sometimes for a fraction of a second, sometimes longer. I've tried to add `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and `onPageFinished setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. That helps a little bit, but the divs are still visible. If I click on a link in the `WebView`, the next Page shows the divs even longer.

Here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

public WebView mWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    String url = "https://www.example.com";
    mWebView = (WebView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView rootView, String url)
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementById('page-header').remove(); " +
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " +
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " +
                    "})()");
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    return fragmentView;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Help would be very much appreciated. Please excuse me if the code is messy, I'm just a beginner - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the visibility as INVISIBLE in the XML file itself rather than setting it in the Java code. The reason behind this is that you are setting the inflation of the view and then setting the visibility after that, hence, the view would display for the timespan of a brief moment. This works for me and should work for you as well. Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Thanks! I took  `mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` out of the Java file and added `android:visibility="invisible"` in the XML File within the `WebView`. That didn't help - wasn't it the right place?